# Facebook can't set Thumbnail correctly on YouTube videos with Custom Thumbnails - 404 error

Tags: facebook, youtube

Ok - I'm absolutely stumped.  For some reason, Facebook has started having a very hard time with the Open Graph metadata and tags coming in from YouTube videos and then can't set the thumbnail correctly.

I've got some videos and playlists that have a custom thumbnail set and they just never show up properly in the preview when shared on Facebook.

I see this whether I try posting straight into Facebook or by using their Sharing URL Debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I've had this issue happen on videos as well as video playlists.  For example, if I pass a URL into the debugger, YouTube keeps returning bad URL for the thumbnail image like this:

```
Image Unavailable
Error while downloading https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gshPq_mYTXM/maxres2.jpg with HTTP response code: 404
```

Visiting that URL does in fact generate a 404.  If I modify the URL to https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gshPq_mYTXM/maxresdefault.jpg then it loads what is supposed to be the thumbnail for my playlist on youtube.

So why is Facebook grabbing https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gshPq_mYTXM/maxres2.jpg and how do I stop it? Or is something broken by YouTube and it only generates that URL instead of the valid https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gshPq_mYTXM/maxresdefault.jpg?

I have spent several hours trying to debug this with no success.  Even creating new playlists, I still run into the problem.

Comment: Which URL are you sharing on Facebook? And if Youtube have problem then Youtube have to fix it.

Comment: If you check the source code of the YT video page, you will see `<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gshPq_mYTXM/maxres2.jpg">` in there. So this is YouTube’s mistake, not Facebook’s.

Comment: So it’s a YouTube bug? Anyway to get around this? Or perhaps it will resolve itself over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a caching issue.  After 48 hours the issues seemed to have self-resolved and youtube is no longer issuing og:image meta tag with an invalid file.